# SQL: Move records agreeing on both conditions on top

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Having the following table

```
  CompanyID   CompanyName
1 333         Name1
2 333         Name2
3 123         Name1
4 333         Name1
5 444         Name1
6 444         Name1
```

I need all companies having `CompanyID` = `333` `OR` `CompanyName`= `Name1` and I want to write the query in a way that, if I have companies agreeing on both required `CompanyID`(333) and `CompanyName`(Name1) then they should be on the top of the result table like that. Except this other ordering may not be required:

```
  CompanyID   CompanyName
1 333         Name1
2 333         Name1
3 333         Name2
4 123         Name1
5 444         Name1
6 444         Name1
```

How can I achieve this? I'm using SQL Server 2008 RD.
Thanks!

Comment: What will the order of the rest be?

Comment: @christiandev the order of the rest doesn't matter to me

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is an `order by` issue.  You need to put the double matches at the top of the list:

```
select *
from t
where CompanyId = 333 or CompanyName = 'Name1'
order by (case when companyId = 333 and CompanyName = 'Name1' then 1
               else 0
          end) desc
```